# Static classes to store common data between tests

Tags: typescript, playwright

I'm looking for a way to mimic static classes similar to C# with Playwright. For context, we have some flows that are common amongst a good portion of tests, and I'd like to skip doing this flow if it already happened in a previous test and doesn't need to happen again. Then once the next test that requires a different flow runs, we will run that flow.

For example, I've tried the following:

```
// CurrentState

export abstract class CurrentState {  // How I tried to implement a static class
    static userSetting1: boolean = false;
    static userSetting2: boolean = false;
    static userSetting3: boolean = false;
}
```

```
// myPage.ts

export class myPage {
    async setUserSettings(userSetting1: boolean, userSetting2: boolean, userSetting3: boolean) {
        if(userSetting1 != CurrentState.userSetting1 || userSetting2 != CurrentState.userSetting2 || userSetting3 != CurrentState.userSetting3) {
            // follow flow to set the user settings
            // Then update current state to reflect user settings so next test with same settings doesn't do it again
            CurrentState.userSetting1 = userSetting1;
            CurrentState.userSetting2 = userSetting2;
            CurrentState.userSetting3 = userSetting3;
        }
    }
}
```

```
//Tests

test(`1`, async ({page}) => {
    await myPage.setUserSettings(true, false, false);  // Run flow since userSetting1 should be true but is currently false in CurrentState
});

test(`2` async ({page}) => {
    await myPage.setUserSettings(true, false, false);  // Skip flow since same settings as previous
});

test(`3` async ({page}) => {
    await myPage.setUserSettings(false, true, false);  // Run flow since user settings differ for this test
});
```

My assumption is that this should work, at least for tests running with the same worker, which is already a step in the right direction saving the time for each subsequent flow that wouldn't need to run.

Instead, when I'm checking the CurrentState values, the resolve to undefined.

Comment: Having bare boolean parameters is pretty unreadable, IMO. I would use a config object so the caller can easily determine what the params mean. For the "static class", a plain object with a typed interface should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Could you elaborate a little bit on using a plain object?  My concern was if it's instantiated, that when the second test runs, it won't maintain the previous userSettings as it will get re-instantiated with each separate test run.

Comment: It'll work for that too, but then I guess I don't understand the purpose of the code since I thought the idea was persisting some state between tests. Tests should be idemtpotent and deterministic, meaning they don't require a particular order to run.